# How to specify 422 8bit ProRes with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, prores

I understand that if I want 444 10 bit, I use pix_fmt yuva444p10le, but what about if I want 8 bit 422?  Using yuv422p does not work, and if I leave the pix_fmt field blank ffmpeg always defaults to using yuv422p10le (note the 10le at the end, which I see this in the terminal window) no matter what ProRes profile I choose.  Is there a switch to just specify 8 bit?  I am confused about the 10le.

Comment: ProRes encoder only supports 10-bit formats.